# How to query rows by month and group by column using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has two columns - `result` and `time`

I'm trying to get a count of how many rows exist of each `result` in a particular month. There are only two options for result `success` and `failure`

I've managed to get a count of how many rows there are in each month, but I can't get the individual count of how many `success` and how many `failure` there were in each month.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT result, MONTH(time) MONTH, COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM mytable
WHERE YEAR(time)=2017
GROUP BY MONTH(time);
```

I'm looking for a result that provides me with something like there were 12 successes and 8 failures in a particular month.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT result, MONTH(time) MONTH, 
       sum(result = 'success') as success_count,
       sum(result = 'failure') as failure_count
FROM mytable
WHERE YEAR(time) = 2017
GROUP BY result, MONTH(time);
```

Comment: Well that was quick, thank you, it seems to work perfectly! I'll accept the answer when the time frame allows!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following query:

```
SELECT,
    DATE_FORMAT(time, '%m %Y') AS month_year,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS success_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'failure' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS failure_count
FROM mytable
WHERE YEAR(time) = 2017
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(time, '%m %Y')
```

Note that you should be aggregating by time period alone, and not by the `result`, which instead is part of the sum in the `CASE` expression.